# '-[CIContext initWithOptions:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift

I used this to generate a big image:

```
let context = CIContext(options: nil)
let bitmapImage: CGImageRef = context.createCGImage(image, fromRect: extent)!
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmapRef,  CGInterpolationQuality.None)
CGContextScaleCTM(bitmapRef, scale, scale);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmapRef, extent, bitmapImage);
let scaledImage: CGImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapRef)!
return UIImage(CGImage: scaledImage)
```

It worked well in iOS 9 and 10 but not 8. I  got this in the debugger:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CIContext initWithOptions:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f868d5dc8e0'

In addition. I tried to use `let context = CIContext()` instead. But I got nil in the second line. I'm using Xcode 8 and Swift 2.3. Please help me with this! Thanks!

Comment: Which line causes the crash?

Comment: @matt The 1st line.

Comment: I can guess what the problem is. You've hit a bug where on iOS 8, `init(options:)` is not being correctly translated into Objective-C `contextWithOptions:`. You might have to write that line in Objective-C.

Comment: @matt So  should I write this in Objective-C and import it? Thanks for your professional help!

Comment: Do you know how to do it? Wait a sec, I'll write it up for you...

Comment: Okay, wrote up instructions. Not tested as I have no iOS 8 simulator.

Comment: I can confirm that it's specific to XCode 8. The issue does not appear when running the same code on the same device but built from XCode 7.3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have no idea if this will work, but we should try it: let's write that line in Objective-C. So:

### ContextMaker.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

@interface ContextMaker : NSObject

+ (CIContext*) makeMeAContext;

@end
```

### ContextMaker.m

```
#import "ContextMaker.h"

@implementation ContextMaker

+ (CIContext*) makeMeAContext {
    return [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
}

@end
```

### Bridging Header:

```
#import "ContextMaker.h"
```

### Swift:

```
let c = ContextMaker.makeMeAContext()
```

It will only take you a moment to try it, so give it a go and see if we can get past that troublesome line...

Comment: By the way, we shouldn't have had to do that; if you have time, you might file a bug with Apple.