# Use CIContext passed through function instead of UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions

Tags: swift

I have a function that has `UIGraphicsBeginImageWithContextWithOptions()` and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext(`, but the function already passes a CIContext called "context". I'd like to reuse this context for performance since this function is being called many times per second instead of creating a new one every function call.

```
    let sourceCore = ciImage
    let scaledSourceImage:UIImage = UIImage(ciImage:ciImage)

    let size = scaledSourceImage.size.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 0.5))
    let hasAlpha = false
    let scale: CGFloat = 1.0 // use scale factor of main screen

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, !hasAlpha, scale)
        scaledSourceImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

How do I draw and get an image from the current context with the context I passed through the function? By default the context is nil, and I can see that I can initialize it with `context = CIContext(options: <#T##[String : Any]?#>)`, but I can't find how to write those options anywhere.

Interestingly, I can create a CGImage with that passed context with it being supposedly nil with `context.createCGImage(image, from: image.extent)`!.

**EDIT** - Is it a bug in Swift? ['-[CIContext initWithOptions:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39939415/cicontext-initwithoptions-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

I do want options to pass the size and scale, but that thread shows you *should* be able to use nil for options and draw in the context without it crashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing apples and oranges. If you have a CIImage, you can render it *either* by calling CIContext's `createCGImage` *or* by turning it into a UIImage and drawing it into an image graphics context. You don't do *both*. In your code, which uses the second approach, there is no place for CIContext.

Comment: It seems that this among other similar parts of this function is making my device use way too much of the processor. So I guess my original approach is using the current context anyway and not creating a new one?

Comment: Furthermore, I wonder how someone would actually choose a context they'd like to currently use if they made many.

Comment: Making a CIContext once is less expensive than make a CIContext repeatedly, but it won't impact the fact rendering a CIImage into a bitmap image, no matter how you do it, is expensive. For this reason, you should perform such rendering in a background thread. A much less CPU-expensive way to display a CIImage is to use GLKView or CAEAGLLayer (presumably because this uses the GPU instead).

Comment: Looks like I'll have to look into running it on Metal. The background thread seems to have no effect.

Comment: There are some WWDC 2018 videos about Core Image you might want to look at.